# Form under Loop construct not working as expected

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, jsp

**Improper Form Submission**

For the below code snippet, I am not able to get any value for the input hidden field in my request.

In the form table created:

It is **working fine**, if I click the Approve button of the **first** row.

Issue is **faced** when Approve button of intermediate row is clicked.
There is no any value passed in the request for the id="hidinput";

```
<script>
function fetchID(){
var contentID = document.getElementById("testID").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("hidinput").value=contentID;
}
</script> 

       
        <%for (APPL_Testimonial_Txn testimonial_Txn : results) {%>
        
        <tr>
        <form action="<%=approve.toString()%>" method="POST">
        
            <td id="testID"><%=testimonial_Txn != null ? testimonial_Txn
                        .getTestimonialId() : ""%></td>

            <input type="hidden" name="rowId" id="hidinput" value=""/>
            <td><button class="button-continue ContinueNew" type="submit" 
                        onclick="fetchID()">APPROVE</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
```

Please find below screen capture of the table.
[image]

Comment: for a start id tags are supposed to be unique, also why do you create a new form for each row?

Comment: i need to get the value for the 1st <td> that i need to pass to my controller or action method.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code above, there is no way to figure out the row in which approve button was clicked. You can pass the testimonial Id to a fetchID function.

```
<script>
    function fetchID(contentID){
      document.getElementById("hidinput").value=contentID;
    }
    <script>
```

```
    <tr>
    <form action="<%=approve.toString()%>" method="POST">

        <td><%=testimonial_Txn != null ? testimonial_Txn
                    .getTestimonialId() : ""%></td>

        <input type="hidden" name="rowId" id="hidinput" value=""/>
        <td><button class="button-continue ContinueNew" type="submit" 
                    onclick="fetchID('<%=testimonial_Txn != null ? testimonial_Txn
                    .getTestimonialId() : ""%>')">APPROVE</button></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion. 
I changed the position of form tags, means kept form tag **outside** the loop construct keeping form as unique and it worked. :)